# JavaScript import for lit-element gives me 404 not found error in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I have installed lit-element via npm in ASP.NET MVC 5 solution. I am trying to create a starter 
 tag as described in https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start guide. In browser, I get "GET http://localhost:64580/node_modules/lit-element/lit-element" net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in chrome.

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/my-element.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
</body>
```

my-element.js

```
import { LitElement, html } from "../node_modules/lit-element/lit-element";

class MyElement extends LitElement {

    render() {
        return html`
      <!-- template content -->
      <p>A paragraph</p>
    `;
    }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Likely the file is not where you have it specified - one relative path, one fixed might be the issue here: http://localhost:64580/node_modules/lit-element/lit-element should perhaps be http://localhost:64580/Scripts/node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js or some such

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `import` as

import { LitElement, html } from "lit-element";

Comment: Well that's given in the documentation as well, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This can resolve this issue
Import like this

```
import {
  html,
  LitElement,
} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element@latest/lit-element.js?module';
```